# GMOD LUA: Can't set random player model

Tags: lua, lua-table, garrys-mod

```
local models = {
    "models/player/odessa.mdl",
    "models/player/alyx.mdl"
    -- any so on...
}

hook.Add("PlayerSetModel", "RandomPlayerModel", function(ply)
    -- Pick a random model based on the array's length
    local random_model = models[math.random(#models)]
    -- Assign the chosen model to the player
    ply:SetModel(random_model)
end
```

(I am newbie)**I have used this code. But it doesn't work at all. My script is in the gamemode folder and is called "serverscript.lua".Basically, I need the system to automatically change the model to a random one when the player enters the game.**

I tried to fix this problem. **But unfortunately only errors appeared that clung to "hook.ADD" and other syntax errors**. There is absolutely no solution to this problem on the internet.

Here is an article about this class - [https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/GM:PlayerSetModel](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: "script is in the gamemode folder" What is the exact path? Some folders are automatically loaded serverside, others automatically loaded clientside, and others not automatically loaded at all.

Comment: GarrysMod\garrysmod\gamemodes\leftfourgz\gamemode\serverscript.lua

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit GarrysMod\garrysmod\gamemodes\leftfourgz\gamemode. I will be happy if you help me. I will also add that when this script is triggered, errors appear, and the function that should change the player model does not work.